# Rails I18n - Strings with format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

I'm using an HTML template that allows the use of highlighted (bold) texts applying the following format:

```
<h3><span class="semi-bold">Visit</span> details</h3>
```

That will be rendered as something like:

> **Visit** details

I want to add an I18n layer to the title, but i find that in the different languages, the text highlighting order may vary:

> (en) **Visit** details
>
> (es) Detalles de **visita**

I find disgusting the idea of putting the HTML in the language files (i could like to use the strings in a different context):

```
en:
  visit_details: '<span class="semi-bold">Visit</span> details'
es:
  visit_details: 'Detalles de <span class="semi-bold">visita</span>'
```

Does Rails offer a better method to handle this kind of formatted i18n texts?

Comment: could you explain more, like who highlights the text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you to do as the following:

```
# view
t('menus.object_details', object: content_tag(:span, t('menus.visit'), class: 'semi-bold')).html_safe

# en.yml
en:
  menus:
    object_details: "%{object} details"
    visit: "Visit"

# some_other_locale.yml
some_other_locale:
  menus:
    object_details: "Details %{object}"
    visit: "Visit"
```

As you can see, the I18n file does not contain any hard-coded HTML element.

The trick here is how to handle masculine/feminine(/neutral) nouns (ex: French, German).

Comment: This solution is not good.
I18n is used to translate the text and keep the context. 
For example if I have the text "Visit details" in EN, the work order could change and could be translated in other language to something like "Details visit". This could happen in Czech, Hebrew, Arabic etc.
The way your solution is, you have forcing the order of words which will not work.

Comment: @CodeMonkey The words order is handled by each locale. If you want to change the word order for another language, let's say "Details visit" for Spanish (I know it's wrong but I use it for the example), you would define the I18n key es.menus.object_details to "Details %{object}". See my answer's update.

Comment: @mrYoshiji you are forcing the translator to know the whole context of the strings to translate. How would the translator know that "object_details" and "visit" are tied together to form "details visit" or "visit details"? he needs to know the code to do that... Right now, the translator will translate "details ..." and "visit". This does not mean it will work as a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

OH, do this:

```
# en.yml
en:
  menus:
    object_details: "%{Visit} details"

# some_other_locale.yml
some_other_locale:
  menus:
    object_details: "Details %{Visit}"
```

```
# in view
t('menus.object_details', Visit: content_tag(:span, 'Visit', class: 'semi-bold')).html_safe
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.